# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, web.config

Tenho uma aplicação **Asp.Net MVC 4 (com Entity Framework e SQL Server)** que funciona normalmente em meu servidor de aplicação, mas agora tive que trabalhar com redundância e load balance com dois novos servidores para a aplicação (descartando o antigo). Em cada um dos servidores segui o básico instalando todos os recursos necessários e configurando a aplicação no IIS. **O banco de dados está em um servidor a parte e não sofreu alterações.**

Depois de dar start no primeiro servidor novo, testei a aplicação que funcionou perfeitamente, mas ao dar start no segundo servidor novo e iniciar os testes recebi o seguinte erro:

> **A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
> server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection
> is not usable)**
>
> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the
> execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
> for more information about the error and where it originated in the
> code.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
> transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
> server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection
> is not usable)

Dei uma pesquisada e encontrei [este artigo da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx), onde me baseio para creditar que o problema esteja relacionado ao pooling de conexão.

Algumas dúvidas surgiram:

1- O pooling de conexão é controlado pelo ADO.Net do servidor de Banco de Dados ou por cada um dos servidores de aplicação?

2- Quais são as possíveis causas do problema?

3- Como posso resolver? Alguma configuração como `'Connection Lifetime'` e `'Max Pool Size'` no `Web.config`? (O que tais configurações fazem e por que são uma possível solução?)

Comment: Já tentou reciclar o Application Pool? Como está sua conexão com a base de dados?

Comment: Sim, quando pergunta sobre como está a conexão, quer dizer se está funcionando ou como fiz no Web.config?

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar desativando o Pooling, colocando na string de conexão `Pooling=false;`

Comment: Esse seu problema pode ser causado por diversos fatores. Poste o que você fez para resolver como resposta, que depois adicionar os outros, para complemento.